# Creating an external SpringBoot service that lives in its own jar

Tags: spring-boot, dependency-injection, configuration

I'm trying to create a general purpose springboot service in a jar file that can be used across several applications.  To do this I have create a jar file (using maven) that has the following:

A set of three classes and one interface in this single jar.  They are in their own distinct package:

```
package com.hmg.generic.service

MyServiceConfig
MyServiceDataSourceConfig
MyService
IMyService
```

I have a main application in a separate project, that contains

```
@ComponentScan(basePackages = {"com.hmg.apps.myapplication","com.hmg.generic.service"})
public class MyApplication extends SpringBootServletInitializer {
```

My question is, how do I annotate the classes, and do I need any kind of factory method, or helper code, to get the classes in the jar to be instantiated and spun up when the application starts?

When I try to spin up the application I get the following message:

```
Field config in com.hmg.app.myapplication.MyApplication required a single bean, but 2 were found:
    - myServiceConfig: defined in file [/Users/tgia/Development/source/MyApp/GenericService/target/classes/com/hmg/generic/service/MyServiceConfig.class]
    - com.hmg.generic.service.MyServiceConfig: defined in null
```

I want it to be a library, that contains a class, that is used like any other service in my application. I don't want to spin it up like a separate application.  To included it as one of the parameters on the constructor of the class where it's going to be used.

```
@Component
public class AccountResource {


    AccountResource(IMyService runtime, AccountInfoService accountInfoService,    
AppInfo appInfo) {
        this.runtime = runtime;
        this.accountInfoService = accountInfoService;
        this.appInfo = appInfo;
     }
```

Comment: Do you want that generic "service" to act like an independent running application, or as a library, which you include in other applications?

Comment: Please show how you are initializing/using the field `config` in `MyApplication`

Comment: I added the answers to your questions in the text of the original question